# Design Pattern for multithreaded task overall progress report

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a library with an `IJobMaker` entity that creates a certain amount of `IJob` objects to be run on threads of their own managed by the user.
To track each `IJob`'s progress I implement the observer pattern with an `IProgressObserver` within every job. The difficulty arises when I wish to report on OVERALL progress.

The ideal for me would be to have `IProgressOverserver.ReportProgress(float jobProgress, float overallProgress` that reports both job and overall progress.`IJobMaker` can be aware of each job's portion of the overall work and somehow gather everyone's reports.

Two main questions arise:

1. Synchronization mechanism? Keeping a mutex inside `IJobMaker` for example could harm performance because `IProgressOverserver.ReportProgress` gets called a lot and a mutex could incur a context switch and what not. InterlockedIncrement looks like a good option but since there's no such function for floating point, I would be forced to report progress by integer increments. (I'd like to stay away from c++0x features or Boost)
2. Design pattern? `IJob`'s progress is reported from within its deepest algorithms. I need every such a report to both communicate with a central entity for overall progress calculation and call the `IProgressObserver.ReportProgress` method which resides in `IJob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's quite bad practice to use floats in such cases. Use an integer.

There is another suggestion. You can use segmentation - synchronise only few threads by one mutex/atomic (one segment). And then collect total among all segments.

Also, there is good place to start looking around highly parallel algorithms: http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms

**UDPATE**
There is example of problems with the float

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float f = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<100000-98; ++i)
    {
        f += 0.00001;
    }
    cout << f << endl;
}
```

So, if you have 100 jobs with 1000 steps each, you will have 1.0 result in 98 earlier than you could expect.

Comment: can you elaborate as to why it is bad to use floats? also, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by segmentation. How can I sync only a few threads?

Comment: Floats are designed for wide range of values. I don't think you have progress range between `1E-200` - `1E200`. For your situation you could have `AtomicInteger` and do precise calculations, but I never heard about `AtomicFloat`. Yes, you could group few threads by few segments. It allows sync fewer threads on a single mutex.

Comment: but then I would have to sync the segments to get the final answer. Maybe it would work if I allowed some delay from the moment some `IJob` progresses until the user gets the overall progress report. Yet since I want an immediate answer I'd have to sync within segments and between segments which seems just as hurtful. regarding floats, I can have the range be between 0 and 1. integers are also wide ranged but only a subrange is used.

Comment: Ok, you are right then. In this case the best solution is the atomic integer, I suppose, because it doesn't do syscalls as mutexes. I don't understand you about the range. Just use an integer range e.g. between 0 and 1 billion, it will give better precision than the same size floating number type. Otherwise you could face a problem then `0.01 + ..hundred times.. + 0.01 != 1`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions on the threading front:

1. Don't report every tiniest bit of progress. Only report to the main thread once a certain predefined amount of progress has been made, or a certain predefined amount of time has passed, or the sub-job has finished. This could greatly cut down on the amount of synchronization.
2. If you implement #1, a mutex might work pretty well.
3. If the mutex turns out to be too expensive, you could report progress using an atomic integer variable: simply scale the values from "no progress" to "all done" to `0`...`INT_MAX`.

As far as designing the API, it shouldn't be too difficult to come up with something sensible. My general advice would be to not overengineer it.

Comment: I am reporting as "roughly" as I can and still I believe using a lock could have a bad impact on performance. No matter how far away my reports are, I can always scale things enough to bottleneck on the lock. (having large numbers of threads and `IJob`s) This library should be able to scale to 10s of cores.